# Promise freezes UI until I press any key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to resize multiple images using Image File Resizer. To do this, I run through an array that contains the files and call the shrink function for each file. However, my UI freezes until I press any key, then the promise continues. This happens with every image in the array. So I can't get to the Callback function of the imageFileResizer either.

```
const resizeFile = (file) =>
new Promise((resolve) => {
  Resizer.imageFileResizer(
    file,
    150,
    150,
    "JPEG",
    90,
    0,
    (uri) => {
      resolve(uri);
    },
    "base64"
  );
});

useEffect(() => {
const resizeImages = async () => {
  if (startEffect.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < startEffect.length; i++) {
      //Freezes here until I press a key
      const image = await resizeFile(startEffect[i]);
      setPics((prev) => [...prev, image]);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
};
resizeImages();
}, [startEffect]);
```

Comment: Move setIsLoading outside of the for loop might help